# Curious about overflow property of html and body element in ionic

Tags: overflow, ionic-framework

Recently, I was playing [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). When I tested my page using chrome, I found that I could not scroll down pages. However I performed normally when testing on mobile devices. After investigating ionic css files, I found the reason why I could not scroll vertically is that the overflow property of html and body element was set to hidden. So, I am very confused why should the html and body overflow hidden. I can understand why overflow-x should be hidden. But why overflow-y? Is there someone can help me out of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hidden on the body, html tags because ionic makes use of ion-content and ion-scroll directives to provide scrolling panes for your content. It avoids using the native scroll on your device unless told otherwise. See http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent overflow-scroll="true"

Comment: @JamieSutherland Thanks for responding and it really helps. But I am still confused. Even if provided with ionContent or some other directives like ionScroll, I still don't see the necessity of overflow-y hidden for html and body tags. Looking forward more detailed explanations. Thanks!